# Appending div with image in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am having problem with appending a div with an image to a page after clicking a link.
Here is my script, which on document.ready() adds the event.

```
var handler = function () {
    $('#content').append("<div class=\"loading-graphic\" style=\"position:absolute;height:200px;width:200px;top:30%;left:40%;z-index:999;\"></div>");
    //$("<div class=\"loading-graphic\" style=\"position:absolute;height:200px;width:200px;top:30%;left:40%;z-index:999;\"></div>").appendTo("div#content");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var ls = document.links, numLinks = ls.length, i = 0; i < numLinks; i++) {

        if (ls[i].parentElement.className != "t-window-actions t-header" && ls[i].parentElement.className != "t-widget t-numerictextbox") {
            ls[i].onclick = handler;
        }
    }
})
```

The problem here that it doesn't work in Chrome while in Firefox and IE its working perfectly. After some digging i found out that it actually adds the div but doesn't show the image. (Tested it with adding the div on the beginning of the page, everything moves down and the div is empty)

I have tested it also adding it directly to page and then it works good but it's not what I'm looking for unfortunately.

Here is my css class:

```
.loading-graphic
{
    background: url('~/Content/ico/loading_big.gif') no-repeat;
}
```

Got no idea what is causing the problem. Anyone got an idea? ;/

Comment: Have you tried deleting the ~ from your file path?

Comment: Won't help since I am using other classes like that with different images loaded and they work correctly in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly sometimes Chrome screws up. I have had issues with Chrome and background images, but it was only my computer. Try it on a different computer Chrome browser, it might not be the same.

The other thing I would suggest is, have your div coded already instead of appending it. So basically have it on the html code and position it out of sight, then when you need it, just move it to the right position.

Comment: I am one of the developers of thee app and I we tried couple of solutions etc. On none of the other computers it worked ;/ I guess you are right and im gona have to add that div manualy to every page. :
Edit: or the layout page :D

Answer (score 1):

It was the background position; also increased z-index, attached to body, and prevented other invisibility reasons.

```
var handler = function () {
    $('body').append("<div class=\"loading-graphic\" style=\"position:absolute;height:200px;width:200px;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-100px 0 0 -100px;z-index:99999;background-position:center center;display:block !important;\"></div>");
}
```

Comment: Tried your solution and it didn't seem to help. I managed to get it working for a moment but it was from a Telerik menu item click I'll investigate further.